# Can't install Steam on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, steam

I installed Ubuntu 16.10 in a dualboot with Windows 10. I tried to install Steam but it shows this in the Terminal:

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 [sudo] password for user:
```

When I enter the password:

```
............ Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: The following packages have unmet dependencies: gcc-6-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed libc6-dev-x32 : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.24-3ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed libgl1-mesa-dri : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (!= 12.0.3-1ubuntu2) but 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.10.1 is to be installed libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (>= 2.4.63) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libdrm-intel1:i386 (>= 2.4.48) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (>= 2.4.66) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (>= 2.4.31) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.66) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libelf1:i386 (>= 0.142) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libexpat1:i386 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libgcrypt20:i386 (>= 1.7.0) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libllvm3.8:i386 but it is not going to be installed Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed Recommends: libtxc-dxtn-s2tc:i386 but it is not installable or libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 but it is not going to be installed or libtxc-dxtn0:i386 Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri (!= 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.10.1) but 12.0.3-1ubuntu2 is to be installed libgl1-mesa-glx : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (!= 12.0.3-1ubuntu2) but 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.10.1 is to be installed libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libexpat1:i386 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.10.1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libx11-6:i386 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libx11-xcb1:i386 but it is not going to be installed Depends: libxcb-dri2-0:i386 (>= 1.8) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libxcb-dri3-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed Depends: libxcb-glx0:i386 (>= 1.8) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libxcb-present0:i386 but it is not going to be installed Depends: libxcb-sync1:i386 but it is not going to be installed Depends: libxcb1:i386 (>= 1.9.2) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libxdamage1:i386 (>= 1:1.1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed Depends: libxfixes3:i386 but it is not going to be installed Depends: libxshmfence1:i386 but it is not going to be installed Depends: libxxf86vm1:i386 but it is not going to be installed Depends: libudev1:i386 but it is not going to be installed Breaks: libgl1-mesa-glx (!= 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.10.1) but 12.0.3-1ubuntu2 is to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution). Press return to continue:
```

And when I press return is shows an error log which says:

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libGL.so.1 Press enter to continue
```

Please help. ;(

Answer (score 1):

Generally the problem here is that the dependencies steam requires are not being installed.  The command errors out because your system packages are in a bad state, you can see that in the full output from your second paste.

You'll need to run "sudo apt-get -f install" as suggested by the error output and hope that it can fix it.  In some cases, it might not be able to in which case you will need to seek further output with the exact output of that command.

Comment: For more clarity.. if apt-get -f install has no problem and then "apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 " still fails then something is quite broken on your system likely due to adding some bad apt sources, or not having the correct apt sources.  This is less likely, but possible.  Hoepfuly apt-get -f install will fix it.